# Links / Pointers to tutorials on "How to have Calender / Scheduler View in Visual Force Pages"

Tags: visualforce, calendar

Hi I am new to visual force development. I got a requirement to implement a visual force page similar to Google or outlook calender and will have many other controls as well. I did search and found few like Dhtmlx and Full calender. But after integration , they are not rendering properly.

I am getting doubt whether they really worked for some one or not? I would like to have a some pointers and links of tutorials which really worked for some one. Which I will follow to have the basic implementation first and modify or customize according to my need. Please suggest the links which worked for you !!

Answer (score 1):

I've used [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in a Salesforce app successfully. You need to have decent JavaScript debugging skills to get this sort of code working.

Here are two blog posts I wrote on the subject that include sample code:

- [FullCalendar quick start](http://force201.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/fullcalendar-quick-start/)
- [FullCalendar using a JavaScript remoting callback](http://force201.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/fullcalendar-using-a-javascript-remoting-callback/)

Comment: Thanks @Keith, It's works for me. But the in the example the Full calender version was old one , I used the latest versions to make my work done. But your pointer is a help.

Answer (score 0):

Found below link also do explains how to integrate the full calender(Newer versions)

http://www.codebycody.com/2013/06/create-calendar-view-in-salesforcecom.html